# invalid resource directory (directory or signature have been modified)

Tags: ios, xcode

I developed a cocoa-touch-framework and embedded it in a host project.

When i run the project it gives me this error regarding my framework:

> Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
>   /Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VeediDemoApp-euimfgwxsvkcoubazudmykjmdapx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/VeediDemoApp.app/Frameworks/VeediFramework.framework: **replacing existing signature**
>   /Users/Michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VeediDemoApp-euimfgwxsvkcoubazudmykjmdapx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/VeediDemoApp.app/Frameworks/VeediFramework.framework: **invalid resource directory (directory or signature have been modified)**
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

In my framework i am signing the framework with this settings:

Code sigining identity -> "Dont code sign" -> "IOS Developer" (Any ios sdk)
Proviosioning profile set to Automatic

I want to sign my framework with the general IOS developer since the hosting project will resign it anyway.

Everything worked fine until i think i revoked certificate in the hosting project (but the error is pointing on the framework)

How to fix this?